# How to get users not in role,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles, roleprovider

Is there any reasonably efficient way to get a list of users who are not in a specific role?

The only methods I can see are

1. Get all the users from DB and do a check in code
2. Go directly to the db and sidestep the role provider

Comment: Care to supply some info about the DB structure?

Comment: @Aidiakapi, the structure is fixed. It is part of the framework.

Comment: I know there is one, but I thought it was customizable.

Answer (score 4):

You could just get the all user list and extract users in role specified from the list:

```
var usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("admin");
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers()
    .Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .Select(u => 
        !usersInRole.Contains(u.UserName)
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

Changing the Select to Where in the code provided by Alex will actually return the results instead of just true/false.

```
var usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("admin");
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers()
    .Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .Where(u => 
        !usersInRole.Contains(u.UserName)
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to extend RoleProvider with the method GetUsersNotInRole() and query the DB there. You can also combine RoleProvider.GetUsersInRole() with MembershipProvider.GetAllUsers() and find the difference

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is anything wrong with by-passing the role provider and querying the database directly. You will definitely get the best performance this way.

Comment: Agreed, basically what you want is a sprok that does this `SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM UsersInRoles ur
   WHERE ur.RoleId = '8E79BA23-E568-423F-80F3-AF60C33DC7EB'
   AND ur.UserId = u.UserID
)`

Answer (score 1):

Found this way, hope this helps others aswell. Very easy.

```
 var usernames = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Administrator");

            var adminUsers = db.UserProfiles
                 .Where(x => !usernames.Contains(x.UserName)).ToList();
            return View(adminUsers);
```